# How to model this Category and Product relationship in RDBMS?

Tags: database-design, database-schema, rdbms, erd

I am trying to design a database for nested categories of products, e.g. "men/shoes/sandals", "women/shoes", or "men/jeans".

I can model it with two entities `Category` and `Product`. The "subcategory" Category-to-Category relationship is many-to-many. Every `Category` has zero or many subcategories. Every `Category` has zero or many parent `Categories`. For example, "jeans" is a subcategory of categories "men" and "women", category "men" has subcategories "jeans" and "shoes", etc. I believe `Category` entities form a DAG (direct acyclic graph) and can be modeled with a "join table".

In this model a `Product` belongs to a *path* in this DAG. For example, a product can belong to *path* "men/shoes/sandal" but not to category "men" or category "sandal". Does it make sense ? How would you model this Product-to-Category relationship ?

Another problem is the order of products. I would like to display products in category `men/shoes` in some particular order. How would you suggest store this order in the database ?

Answer (score 2):

Since category-to-category is a many-to-many relation, a well-known approach to this is to create a many-to-many table, called

**subcategory(id, parent_category_id, child_category_id)**

Since products are not belonging to categories per se, but to a set of ordered categories, paths, this is how you could model it:

**product_path(id, product_id, category_id, order_index)**

where `order_index` represents the order in which the items of the path are sorted, so a path of `men/shoes/sandals` would be represented by 3 `product_path` records, the first being a connection between the `product` and the `category` of men, the second being a similar connection with the `category` of `shoes` and the third would be a similar `category` of `sandals`.

Since you intend to have a particular `product` order for each category, in this problem-space you have two main options:

1. You can create a **product_category_order(id, product_id, category_id, order_index)** and store a record for each orders in the category
2. You can create a **product_category_order(id, category_id, products)** table, where you would have a comma-separated value or a JSON for `products`

Option 2. violates normal form theory, but for practical reasons you may decide to put aside theory in this case. Really, the exact scenario that you have determines whether option 1 or option 2 are better matches for your task.

Comment: Thanks ! Now I wonder how to get all products by nested category, e.g. "men/shoes/sandals". I will add a new question about it.

Comment: @Michael I thought it probable that this will be a next problem, as this was my thought process as well when I solved this kind of issue for the first time. Please let me know about your new question when you post it, also, when you ask the new question, it is advisable to share the exact schema that you have, along with sample data (possibly a SQL fiddle as well) and whether we are allowed to solve it using application code (if so, which one). Finally, if the maximum depth is known, that can be a helpful information as well.